Can someone get flagged for answering wrongly at a Schengen immigration on a tourist visa even though allowed to enter?
Can someone get flagged for answering wrongly at a Schengen immigration on a tourist visa even though allowed to enter? Like for example say mentioning incorrect number of days to stay in the country but later clarified with the officer and being allowed to enter
